# PassWordChangeForm for other user than current one

Tags: django

I tried to follow some tutorials to implement the password change functionality, but the problem is, that its always for the currently authenticated user. I want for example an admin to be able to change the password of another user (not through the admin panel).

```
class PasswordChangeForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PasswordChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['old_password'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['new_password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['new_password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

My view looks like this:

```
def changepassword(request):
    user = User.objects.get(id = request.POST.get("id"))
    if request.POST.get("type") == "user_changepw":
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=user)
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'user_changepw.html')
```

The user is coming here from a list of all the users with corresponding buttons that have as input the id of that user and also a hidden input "user_changepw", so that the form isnt throwing errors the first time you get on the site. But this also seems to be the problem, because after that the "id" value in the POST request is lost, so that the attempt to fetch the user form the DB always fails, beacuse `request.POST.get("id")` is now None. What we be a good solution to keep the user-id in the function or how to pass it through so that it persists also cases, where the form threw errors?

Comment: A POST request ideally changes some data in the server. Your button only takes you to this page and no change is done. That suggests that your button should in fact just be an anchor tag to this page (you can easily pass the user's id in the url).

Comment: Is this the only way? For some reasons not coming from me the desired behaviour is that the id won't show up in the url.

Comment: Then just put the id in the form as a hidden input.